# adding foreign key constraint locks up table

Tags: sql, mysql, database, postgresql, migration

I have a table "aaa" which is not very big. It has less than 10'000 rows. However read operations on this table is very frequent.

Whenever I try to create a new table "bbb" with foreign key pointing to "aaa". The operation locks, and reading "aaa" is not possible. The query also never seems to finish.

```
ALTER TABLE "bbb" ADD CONSTRAINT "topic_id_refs_id_3942a46c6ab2c0b4" FOREIGN KEY ("topic_id") REFERENCES "aaa" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

The current workaround is to create any new table at off-peak hours, e.g. midnight after restarting the db.

I would like to know if there's any proper solution of this. Is this an issue affecting all relational databases? My db is PostgreSQL 8.3.

Answer (score 2):

`ALTER TABLE` needs a table lock, so you can't use the table for reads. Your problem sounds like a problem with locks, check pg_stat_activity to see what is going on.

Offtopic: Why do you restart your database after midnight? We never restart the database, there is no need for it.

Comment: Just a question: ALTER TABLE is used on table "bbb". Is there still a lock on table "aaa"? Does the ALTER TABLE statement lock both tables?

Comment: Yeah, if you have to restart the db, you likely have lingering connections that are holding some kind of locks they shouldn't be.

Comment: will take note of the restart part.